# Set printf dynamic format for trailing whitespaces

Tags: printf

Any standard way to make the '%-6s' format for printf dynamic?

```
function justify
{
echo "$(printf '%-6s' $1)"
}
```

I tried inserting variable into the format but I'm getting *Error processing format* error.

```
$(printf '%-${2}s' ${1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure what you were intending by passing the command substitution to `echo`, but this should do the trick:

```bsh
justify() {
    printf "%-${2}s\n" "$1"
}
```

If you had `$1` unquoted in order to pass multiple arguments, consider using `"$@"` instead.

There are a few things to note in relation to your existing attempt:

1. Variables aren't expanded in single quotes, use double quotes.
2. There's no need to use a command substitution, just call the command directly.
3. (Optional) Avoid `function`, which is non-POSIX.

Comment: thank you for this and this solve my problem. I doing a refactoring of old bash scripts and this command substitution didn't caught my attention.
and ++ for additional explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes; the `$` is treated as a literal dollar sign. You should use double quotes to have `${2}` expanded as a shell variable:

```
printf "%-${2}s" ${1}
```

Your question isn’t completely clear as using command substitution to pass the output of `printf '%-6s' $1` as the input parameters to `echo` removes whatever space characters were printed by the `printf` command. It seems to me that your function would be better written as:

```bsh
justify()
{
    printf "%-${2}s" $1
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, just like the accepted answer but with additional explanation the effect of echo to printf output

Answer (score 0):

At least in bash 4.4+, it appears to be possible to use a C style<sup>1</sup> `*` to access the next available argument as a width or precision. So for example:

```
justify ()
{
    printf '%-*sbar\n' "$2" "$1"
}

$ justify foo 6
foo   bar
```

(`bar` suffix just included to make the width of `foo` apparent); or

```
pround ()
{
    printf '% *.*f\n' "$2" "$3" "$1"
}

$ pround 123.45678 12 3
     123.457
```

---

<sup>1</sup> see `man 3 printf` for example

Comment: this for demo examples, and rounding function there, and yes this solution works for me as well, just excluding the sbar